# Can't see GUI in tkinter library

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have an exercise with tkinter library. I write code with gui in PyCharm but if I run a code nothing happen.

I tried to run that in cmd prompt but script is running again in PyCharm and nothing happen.

I tried also run script with cmd prompt as default to open .py format but nothing happen again.

Do you have any suggestions how can I run my script and see GUI ?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter, sys

def koniec():
    sys.exit()

def zmiana():
    l.config(text = 'Wcisnij zakoncz')

main = tkinter.Tk()

l = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Wcisnij przycisk ponizej')
b = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Zakoncz', command = koniec())
b2 = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Przycisk', command = zmiana)

l.pack()
b.pack()
b2.pack()


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: replace `b = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Zakoncz', command = koniec())
` with `b = tkinter.Label(main, text = 'Zakoncz', command = koniec)` without the calling paren `()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what i came up with, i included a way to center the gui in your monitor maybe it will come in handy yes? anyway good luck on your project

```
import sys
from tkinter import Label, Tk, TRUE, FALSE, Button

window = Tk()
window.resizable(width=TRUE, height=FALSE)
window.title("Try this :)")
window.geometry("250x150")
def center(window):
    window.update_idletasks()
    w = window.winfo_screenwidth()
    h = window.winfo_screenheight()
    size = tuple(int(_) for _ in window.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
    x = w/2 - size[0]/2
    y = h/2 - size[1]/2
    window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (size + (x, y)))
center(window)

def koniec():
    window.destroy()


def zmiana():
    l.config(text = 'Wcisnij zakoncz')

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

l = Label(window, text="Wcisnij przycisk ponizej:")
b = Button(text="Close?", command=koniec )
b2 = Button(text = 'Przycisk', command = zmiana)

l.pack()
b.pack()
b2.pack()
#Main Starter
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: also i used button instead of label, you're running a command my friend, command is like do something, label well it's just for labeling, y'know what i mean right? so if you need to execute commands from your definitions you best use a button or something that would trigger an event like mouse or keyboard or yes a button

Comment: @lenncb no problem bro :) up-vote for my answer if its useful thanks